# How to initialize this array so that it works in the while loop?

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans

I am trying to initialize an array above a while loop and then use the array set the values of the array in the while loop. But netbeans keeps giving me an error message.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
         int a=999;
         int b=999;
         int c=0;
         int[] array = new int[5];
         int[] array2=  new int[6];

         while(c<=998001){
         c=a*b;
         if(c<100000){ 

         array[]={c%100000,c%10000,c%1000,c%100,c%10} 
        //netbeans keeps telling me that this array is "not a statement" 
        ";" expected. Why does it tell me this?// 

          }

            if(array[0]==array[5] & array[1]==array[3]){
                    int d=c;
            }  
          }
         }
```

Comment: BTW, array[5] will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception.  But you've probably already figured that out by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your syntax isn't valid Java. It seems you want to create a new 5 element array with your statement. You could do so like

```
array = new int[] { c % 100000, c % 10000, c % 1000, c % 100, c % 10 };
```

But since you always have five elements, it would probably be more efficient to use a loop and re-use the same array. Like,

```
if (c < 100000) {
    int fac = 100000;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = c % fac;
        fac /= 10;
    }
}
```